# Different css style before and after hover

Tags: css, svg, hover, mouseover, mouseout

I have an svg object and I want it to be styled differently:
a) the first time the image loads (fill: white)
b) when the mouse hovers over the object (fill: yellow)
c) when the mouse leaves the object (fill: blue)

I can't seem to find how to seperate the a) and c) states.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `:hover` only has two states...not three....you need javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to stackoverflow so this might not be a good answer, but I will try to answer this correctly.

What I think you should try is using jQuery, what you would do is set the beginning value in CSS, *Fill: White*. Then in jQuery you would u

```
$("YOUR SELECTOR").hover(function(){
$(this).css("background", "yellow");
}, function(){
$(this).css("background", "blue");
});
```

For more explanation on this, go to: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp)

Hope this helps you out, I'm new at stackoverflow so be kind please ;)

Cheers

Comment: Its is certainly a good answer, just a small correction is needed.
Change `$(this).css("fill", "yellow");` to `$(this).css("background", "yellow");` and you are good to go

Comment: There you go ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is easy. You can use mouseleave event to identify that the element has been hovered once, and then use it to change the background of the element.

Here's some code:

```js
jQuery('#square').mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('red')
       jQuery(this).addClass('blue');
});
```

```css
#square{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  }

.red {
  background:red;
  }

#square:hover{
  background:yellow;
  }

.blue {
  background:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square" class="red"></div>
```